# Esx Storage / Management Network Architecture

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, iscsi

Hi I'm trying to find the most reliable and performant solution for a vmWare storage / management network.  Little overwhelmed with the options and limitations hoping for some insight based on my options.

This is a rough idea:

[image]

*3 Dell server's (Plenty of nic's)

2 Synology Nas's (Production and Backup / Failover) (igb iscsi)

2 Hp 1810-G 24*

VM network is on separate switches.

So these switches are not stackable, so I think that means IP Hashing is not an option and i'm on essentials plus so LBT is not going to work.  What would my best option be ?

EDIT

**What the best way to go about configuring this so as i'm getting load balancing and redundancy.**

(From my research so far the best option would multipathing with the production nas on two subnets).

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @joeqwerty What the best way to go about configuring this so as i'm getting load balancing and redundancy.  Especially given the fact that I can't use the two generic out of the box options (LBT IP hashing)

Comment: You won't be able to do true load-balancing as your switches are stacked or VSS'ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iSCSI traffic, you should not be using the built-in NIC teaming capabilities at all.  Instead, you want to have your storage-facing NICs each configured as a capable iSCSI initiator, with ESXi's built-in storage multipathing handling the load balancing and redundancy needs.

See [this VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2038869) for some guidelines on how this should be set up -- the exact deployment mechanism that's recommended depends on your network - whether you're using one subnet or multiple, single target address or multiple, etc.

Comment: So basically each nic would have its own vSwitch and alternate them between the two trunks on the NAS ?

Comment: @bumble_bee_tuna The MPIO policy will dictate how the commands are balanced - setting the policy to round robin will indeed alternate commands between the different NICs.